# TypeError not caught in my web page's global error handling

Tags: javascript, ejs

I was looking for a way to capture all errors/exceptions on my page and send back a generic error-message. The recurrent solutions I find is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function() {
    alert("Error caught");
};
</script>
```

In testing this solution, I would create a variable in my .ejs page and give it a undefined value as such:

```
<% var data = undefined; 
for(var i = 0; data.length; i++){ ...
```

Much to my surprise, I get the full stack of my error on the page instead of the `alert("Error caught")`, something like this:

```
TypeError: C:\xxxxxx\myPage.ejs:28
    26|         <table class="table">
    27|             <tbody>
 >> 28|                 <%
    29|                 
    30|                 if(data === undefined) {
    31| 
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What I am missing here ? Why isn't this error caught ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and closing it does not help. As answer to your question, visit this page: https://repl.it/repls/MasculineUprightCoordinates the error is coming at compile time, so window.onerror wouldn't ever be called.

Comment: @OliverRadini — It is a duplicate. The problem is that the OP doesn't understand that their server side and client side code are two different programs that run at different times (and probably on different computers).

Comment: @BinitGhetiya — They know what the error is. The question is why the exception catching code doesn't catch it.

Comment: @BinitGhetiya The exception catching code isn't catching it because that code is a function added to the window, which is client side. The error is being thrown at compile time, before there even is a window, so the function has no chance to catch the error

Comment: Understand Thank you for clarifying @OliverRadini

Comment: @Quentin I can see where you're coming from, but do you think we can assume that the cause of the problem is not understanding the difference between server side and client side code? It could, for instance, be an issue related to what the OP understands of how ejs compiles its files. I don't think it's completely clear the ejs would interpret the js within script tags.